# href creates footnote instead of clickable link

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, urls, href

I am using the hyperref package in my document. I would like to make a link to a webpage. However, this always creates a footnote. This is probably due to a package conflict, but cannot manage to find the issue.. :(

I use overleaf and my preample is:

```
\documentclass[mainlanguage=english,colophon-location=nowhere,output=paper,localtocs/depth=subsection,version=final]{yathesis}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage[nospace]{varioref}


\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hidelinks, hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{physics}
% \usepackage{braket}

% \usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}


\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[perpage, symbol*]{footmisc}

\usepackage{autonum}
\cslet{blx@noerroretextools}\empty



\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,bibstyle=nature,arxiv=pdf,sorting=none,eprint=false,isbn=false,backref=true,url=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{\thefield{urlraw}}}

%user commands
\newcommand{\ahdag}{\hat{a}^{\dagger}}
\newcommand{\ah}{\hat{a}}

\newcommand{\chdag}{\hat{c}^{\dagger}}
\newcommand{\ch}{\hat{c}}

\newcommand{\Sh}{\hat{S}}

\newcommand{\Hh}{\hat{H}}

\newcommand{\Psihdag}{\hat{\Psi}^{\dagger}}
\newcommand{\Psih}{\hat{\Psi}}



\newcommand{\sigmah}{\hat{\sigma}}
\newcommand{\hc}{ + \mathrm{H.c.} \, }



\newcommand{\ds}{\chi''(\Delta_{\mathrm{pa}})}
\newcommand{\dsa}{\chi_\mathrm{a}(\Delta_{\mathrm{pa}})}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\renyi}{R\'{e}nyi }

\DeclareSIUnit\bar{bar}
\DeclareSIUnit\gauss{G}
\DeclareSIUnit\angstrom{\text {Å}}
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI}
```

The code that makes the issue is

```
\subsection{Optical Layout}
\label{sec:optically_contacted_optics}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=14.7cm, page= 1]{corps/ch1/figures/Optics_design_with_beams.pdf}
    \caption{\textbf{Design of Optically-Contacted Cavity-Microscope.} \textbf{a}, Schematic of optics including the main laser beams. The cavity mirror (light gray) and the aspheric lens (dark gray) are optically contacted together. The cavity mode is shown in red. The focused beams at \SI{460}{\nm} and \SI{780}{\nm} are drawn in blue and orange. \textbf{b}, Picture of final assembly. An open-access online 3D model of the cavity is shown in Ref.~\cite{sauerwein_quems_2023}. Click \href{https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/quems-cavity-v2018-45564251b3074b21a4fdbd6cc4cc4feb}{here} for quick access.}
    \label{fig:design_optically_contacted}
\end{figure}
```

and here the result:
[image]

I had also to use href in my bibliography to make clickable links. This also generates footnotes.

Thanks in advance for your help =)!

Comment: Welocme to TeX.SX! It seems that the class option `output=paper` does this.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much! This was perfect!

Answer (score 3):

The document class has the following lines in its code:

```
\ifbool{YAD@output@paper}{%
  \AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
      \YAD@hypersetup{colorlinks=false}%
      \renewcommand{\YAD@href}[3][]{#3}%
      \let\YAD@ori@footnote\footnote%
      \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\booltrue{YAD@in@footnote}\YAD@ori@footnote{#1}\boolfalse{YAD@in@footnote}}%
      \renewcommand*\url[1]{\nolinkurl{#1}}%
      \renewcommand*\href[3][]{%
        \ifbool{YAD@in@footnote}{%
          #3 (\url{#2}) }{%
          #3\footnote{\url{#2}} }%
      }%
    }{%
    }%
  }%
}{%
}%
```

This means that if you set the option `output=paper`, URLs are printed as footnotes.

However, the option `output=paper` also sets some other things in the document. So, if you want to use this option but not print URLs in footnotes, you can put the following in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\ifbool{YAD@output@paper}{%
  \AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
      \renewcommand*\href[3][]{%
          #3 (\url{#2}) }{%
      }%
    }{%
    }%
  }%
}{%
}%
\makeatother
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[output=paper]{yathesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\ifbool{YAD@output@paper}{%
  \AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
      \renewcommand*\href[3][]{%
          #3 (\url{#2}) }{%
      }%
    }{%
    }%
  }%
}{%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

click \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{here}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot!